# Dirac Function on a Spherical Shell

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

Show that the Dirac function defined as $$\delta)(\rho-\rho_0)=\frac{1}{4\pi} \bigtriangleup \frac{1}{|\rho-\rho_0|} $$

where $\rho=(x_1,x_2,x_3),\rho_0=(x_{1,0},x_{2,0},x_{3,0})$ and $\bigtriangleup=\bigtriangledown  \cdot  \bigtriangledown = div \ grad$ fullfills

1. $\delta(\rho-\rho_0)=0 \ \forall \rho \ne \rho_0$
2. $\int_Vd^3r\delta(\rho-\rho_0)=1$ if $\rho_0 \in V$ and $0$ otherwise.

[image]

This is someone's solution.

I mean what is this,,,shouldnt you use multiple integration to solve this? And if so, how does that go? Everytime when it comes to dirac i just lose it...

Comment: You are correct that the given solution is incorrect. Reason being, while mathematicians will often use one integration sign to refer to any number of dimensions and refer to the divergence theorem as integration by parts, the limits in the integral suggest the person did not understand the exercise and computed in one dimension.

Comment: would you mind showing me how to solve the problem?=

Comment: This is a common exercise that has been on SE many times. If you would rather try the exercise on your own than look for a solution: 1 is easy, simply compute the given derivative by hand. For 2, in the case where $\rho_0\in V$, cut out a small ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $\rho_0$ and use integration by parts to get that surface integral to appear. Then take the limit $\epsilon\to0$

Comment: tbh i did try, typing everything out in latex also took about 20 minutes....